# CSS Way to Know If Page is at Top Most Position

Tags: css

I know this can be done in JavaScript, but let's call that plan B.

Is there a way in CSS to know if the user views the page at its top most position, or must I use JavaScript to achieve this ?

**To clarify using example** - say we denote my wanted output as `atTopMost`:

On initial page load, `atTopMost` equals true.

If the user scrolls the page down even a little bit then `atTopMost` equals false.

If the user scrolls to the top, `atTopMost` equals true.

Comment: Nope, only JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Nope, But javascript yes:

```
if(document.body.scrollTop === 0)
      atTopMost=true;
else
      atTopMost=false;
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not a programming language so, no, you cannot do that with CSS.